# Spring Batch: How to set the first line columns (header), of the csv file to token name for my file reader

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

I have a csv file to consume through spring batch. The column header (names) can differ based on the customer. When reading the data using FlatFileItemReader, how would i set the token name(s) to be the first line (header) column name(s) ? I am using Java Configuration to setup the flow.

Appreciate any comments/suggestions

Comment: Can you, please, edit your answer and add the relevant part of your Java Config?

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to discard the first line of the csv files with the [`FlatFileItemReader::setLinesToSkip`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemReader.html#setLinesToSkip-int-) method. Such as :

```
flatFileItemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set LineToSkip Property :

```
    @Component
    @JobScope
    public class CsvToDbItemReader extends FlatFileItemReader<BillDTO> {
            public CsvToDbItemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters}") Map jobParameters) 
    {
                String uploadDate = (String) jobParameters.get("uploadDate");
                this.setResource(new FileSystemResource(getFileName(uploadDate)));
                this.setLinesToSkip(1); //set header line
                LineMapper<BillDTO> lineMapper = createBillLineMapper();
                this.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
            } 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use as below:

```
<bean id="flatFileItemReader" 
   class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
<!-- linesToSkip => The number of lines to skip at the beginning of the 
    file. This feature is particularly useful to handle file headers. -->
<property name="linesToSkip" value="1" />
```